# How to import images with easyx

Tags: c++

i am following a tutorial,trying to write a game.But when import image,something is wrong.....
fail to import image to code by easyx

```
IMAGE img[12];
void load() {
   LoadImage(&img[0], L"0.jpg", SIZE, SIZE);
}
```

but wrong

```
[Error] elements of array 'ege::IMAGE img [12]' have incomplete type
[Error] storage size of 'img' isn't known
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post links to pictures of text. Instead copy your text directly into the question. You can use the `edit` button below your question to fix this. Also please take a few seconds to pick correct tags. Your code is C++, not C. They are very different languages.

Comment: In addition to what @Gerhardh said, please take some time to [Take The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).